# f(x) = g(x) + i h(x) if g(x) is real even function, h(x) is real odd function how about the root of f(x)=0

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, even-and-odd-functions

I want to know whether f(x)=0 always has complex root if real part of f(x) is a real even function and imaginary part of f(x) is a odd function.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if the following assumptions are wrong:

- $g,h : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
- $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

Otherwise, I don't quite know what definition of even / odd you are using since parity is a rather strange concept in its extension to higher dimensions.

You're question is asking if you are guaranteed a $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$f(c) = g(c) + i h(c) = 0$$

This clearly boils down to a system: 
$$\cases{g(c) = 0 \\
h(c) = 0}$$

The problem with this is that it's now relatively easy to generate a counter-example where $g$ is even, $h$ is odd, yet they share no $c \in \mathbb{R}$ where they are both simultaneously 0. Specifically, consider $g(x) = x^2 + 1$ and $h(x) = x^3$.

So if you want some guarantees on an existence of a zero, you will need some more conditions. Specifically, if you required it to be holomorphic, that might actually give you what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much! @gdepaul My question is whether we can prove that equation f(x) = g(x) + i h(x) = 0 always has complex root x = a + i b or not if we know g(-x)= g(x) and h(-x)=-h(x)